# Jquery .text() on ios with cordova not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I have a JQuery button with an image in the background and when I click it, I want to make text instead of the image so I wrote this:

```
$current.css({ 'background': 'none' });
$current.text('Ok');
```

where `current` is my button.

On an Android device it works perfectly but on iOS, when I click on the button there is `'...'` instead of `'Ok'`

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Did you have the same problem with $current.html('Ok'); ?

Comment: Yes it's the same problem. i have forgotten to specify : console.log($current.text() ) write 'Ok'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: the width was too small to display the text, so I add padding left and rigth to the button